# SonarQube ignore/cancel false positive setting

Tags: sonarqube, false-positive

Is it possible to run Sonar analysis and **ignore that violations were set as *false positive***. For example when somebody else would like to check whether these violations has been marked as *false positive* properly.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible unless you run the analysis of your application with another project key. But the right way to review false positives is to use the Issues page: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Seeing+Issues#SeeingIssues-IssuesServiceandFilters